# does not contain a static main method for suitable entry point

Tags: c#

Keep getting the error message does not contain a static main method for suitable entry point. Would anyone be able to explain this error to me and possibly help me fix it? Thanks.    New to C#

```
 {
    class Authenticator
    {

        private Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public void IntialValues()
        {
            dictionary.Add("username1", "password1");
            dictionary.Add("username2", "password2");
            dictionary.Add("username3", "password3");
            dictionary.Add("username4", "password4");
            dictionary.Add("username5", "password5");
        }

        public bool Authenticate(Boolean authenticated)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a username");
            string inputUsername = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your password");
            string inputPassword = Console.ReadLine();

            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(inputUsername) && dictionary[inputUsername] == inputPassword)
            {
                authenticated = true;
            }
            else
            {
                authenticated = false;
            }

            return authenticated;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If all of your code consists only of this one then the error is more than clear. A Main method is required in your program. It is the point where the code start executing.

Comment: @Steve, how do I go about doing this then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your code consists only of the block shown above then the error is more than clear. A Main method is required in your program.

The Main method is, by convention, the default point where the code starts executing. You can get here a [more in depth explanation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479467/Main-Method-in-Csharp)

So, for example, you need to add the following code

```
class Authenticator
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Authenticator au = new Authenticator();
         au.InitialValues();
         if(au.Authenticate())
            Console.WriteLine("Authenticated");
         else
            Console.WriteLine("NOT Authenticated");
         Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end");
         Console.ReadLine();

    }

    // Move the boolen variable inside the method
    public bool Authenticate()
    {
        bool authenticated = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a username");
        string inputUsername = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your password");
        string inputPassword = Console.ReadLine();

        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(inputUsername) && dictionary[inputUsername] == inputPassword)
        {
            authenticated = true;
        }
        else
        {
            authenticated = false;
        }

        return authenticated;
    }
}
```

By the way, you should remove the parameter passed in input to the Authenticate method. You should declare it as an internal variable, set it depending on the outcome of the check and return it.

However, you could remove that variable altogether writing

```
    ....
    return (dictionary.ContainsKey(inputUsername)) && 
           (dictionary[inputUsername] == inputPassword)
}
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, that did still not work, getting these know.

Comment: Error 3 No overload for method 'Authenticate' takes 0 arguments

Comment: Error 2 '_djv.Authenticator' does not contain a definition for 'InitialValues' and no extension method 'InitialValues' accepting a first argument of type '_djv.Authenticator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: For the first error, then move the _authenticated_ variable inside the method. There is no reason to pass it from the outside. In this way the method doesn't require any parameter. For the second error there is a spelling error in the name of the method. You write **IntialValues** instead of **InitialValues**

Answer (score 0):

All executable programs must have a Main function somewhere in the project that is compiled to the exe.

If you just want to compile a class (eg to a dll) then you have to set that as the "project type" in visual studio.

The easiest way is to create a new project, but select class library as project type, and then paste your code in there.  Alternatively you can use the command line to compile a file to a dll like so:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /target:library Authenticator.cs
```